# Sklearn linear regression X and Y input format

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a few questions about the inputs for the sklearn linear_model.LinearRegression(module).

```
ages_train = [[20, 10000], [22, 12000], [22, 14000], [25, 17000], [30, 29000]]
net_worths_train = [10000, 12000, 14000, 17000, 29000]

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(ages_train, net_worths_train)
```

The above works but it makes it difficult to plot. For example, doing this won't work:

```
plt.scatter(ages_train, net_worths_train, color = "b", label = "train data")
```

And so what I would like to do is input this:

```
ages_train = np.array([20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 31, 31, 34, 42, 50])
net_worths_train = np.array([10000, 12000, 16000, 20000, 30000, 33000, 34000, 38000, 49000, 60000])
```

But this data format doesn't work with the .fit() function of linear_model.LinearRegression. What is the proper way to input data and make it easy to plot as well? And is it preferable to use numpy arrays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [documentation for scikits.learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit). You will see that X and Y need to be two-dimensional arrays of shape (n_samples, n_features) and (n_sample, n_targets) respectively. This is the case even if you only have one feature and one target.

Do you know the difference between an array of shape (6, 1) and an array of shape (6,)? It's a bit confusing at first, but the first is a true 2-dimensional array that happens to have one column, and the second is a completely 1-dimensional array.

Here's how to convert your data to 2d arrays. And yes, you should use numpy, not lists, when working with numerical data like this.

```
ages_train = np.array([20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 31, 31, 34, 42, 50])
net_worths_train = np.array([10000, 12000, 16000, 20000, 30000, 33000, 34000, 38000, 49000, 60000])
reg.fit(ages_train[:, np.newaxis], net_worths_train[:, np.newaxis])
print reg.coef_, reg.intercept_
```

By the way, if you really only want to do simple linear regression, consider [np.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) (polynomial fitting) or [np.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) (generalized least squares). These are easier to install and use. Scikits-learn has many more features and advanced regression techniques, though.

Comment: This `:,np.newaxis` - or rather the problem it solves specifically the `scikit-learn` api's requiring multi-dim arrays where a single dim would suffice - cut short my life by a few months